# angular ngf-select fileupload not working with ngView

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, ng-view, ng-file-upload

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

I'm trying to use this module ngFileUpload.

but it's not working when I use in a template called by ng-view.

This is Working
HTML(index.html)

```
<div ngf-select ng-model="files"></div>
```

But this is not working

HTML(index.html)

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

HTML(test.html)

```
<div ngf-select ng-model="files"></div>
```

JS(angular config)

```
    $routeProvider.when('/test', {
    templateUrl: '/test.html',
    controller: 'testController'
```

any one has same problem like this ?

-thank you for reading..-

Comment: I too Have same issue :( any solution ... ?